# IDE для MSSQL

Tags: ide, sql-server

Для MySQL существует MySQL WorkBench, для ORACLE - SQL Developer.
А какая среда даёт аналогичный функционал для MSSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ms sql management studio express - это бесплатная версия. скачать можно с их сайта

Answer (score 1):

Немного уточню ответ - IDE - MS SQL Management Studio - идет в комплекте со всеми версиями MS SQL Server, кроме версии Express - достаточно удобна для разработки (особенно, если добавить аддонов), поэтому пользуются обычно ей.
Для версии Express ее можно скачать с их сайта - идет отдельным компонентом.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз установил стояла эксперсс - порыскал в папках, но ничего такого не увидел. :)

Answer (score 0):

Так же есть альтернатива SSMS - [dbForge Studio for SQL Server](https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/sql/studio/). Лично я ей не пользовался, но по отзывам говорят классная. Она платная, но есть вариант, если я не ошибаюсь, бесплатный (в некоммерческих целях для одного разработчика). В общем можете посмотреть про неё информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Мне очень нравится HeidiSQL, тоже бесплатная.

http://www.heidisql.com/